# php.ini - wrong path?

Tags: php, apache, centos

I can't make any changes to php.ini. Looks like either I'm editing wrong file or changes are not applied after restarting apache.

Obviously I did run `phpinfo()` and it points to `/etc/php.ini` file. I edited it, then run:

```
sudo apachectl reload
sudo apachectl restart
```

Nothing has changed. I've checked `/etc/php.d` directory (each files) to be sure changes are not overriden by file inside `Scan this dir for additional .ini files`. Not a single file set the lines I need to change.

Using:

- Centos 8 (VPS)
- Zend Engine v3.4.0, Zend OPcache v7.4.19

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem. I had to call:
`sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service`